# Is there a way to delay the restart in SVG animateTransform

Tags: javascript, css, html, image, svg

I am trying to rotate my SVG image along its axis, which I can successfully do with the following code:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                  type="rotate"
                  from="120 262.5 125"
                  to="0 262.5 125"
                  begin="2s"
                  dur="2s"
                  repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
```

My question is whether or not there is a way to deal the restart of the animation by a second or two.  With repeatCount set to indefinite, it immediately restarts it.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I have tried the code given below, but it didn't quite work the way I needed it to.  It needs to rotate around the svg's central axis, but pause for about a second before restarting.  Any ideas?

**FINAL UPDATE**

On the off chance that anyone sees this in the future searching for this issue, I'll provide what I was able to do to get it to work.  By adding an id, changing the begin time and the repeatCount, I was successfully able to get a repetitive rotation with a delay in between.

Here's the code:

```
<animateTransform id="rotation" attributeName="transform"
                  type="rotate"
                  from="120 262.5 125"
                  to="0 262.5 125"
                  begin="2+rotation.end+2"
                  dur="2s"
                  repeatCount=1
 />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG animation delay on each repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690880/svg-animation-delay-on-each-repetition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
    type="rotate"
    from="120 262.5 125"
    to="0 262.5 125"
    begin="0"
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    keyTimes="0;0.75;1" 
     values="0 54.2 43.3 ; 0 54.2 43.3 ; 360 54.2 43.3"
 />
```

here animation begin is specified with relative to animation end, in this way your animation will always wait for your specified time(here 4 sec) and start playing again ...

Comment: That does not quite fix it.  It does create a little bit of a delay, but the rotation is all out of whack.  Maybe if I played with the numbers a little bit...