# SVG animation delay on each repetition

Tags: html, svg, svg-animate, smil

I'd like to add a delay to each iteration of an SVG animation loop. Here's a simple example.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100px" height="100px">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="15" fill="blue">
    <animate id="op" attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity"
             from="1" to="0" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Using `begin` only delays the first iteration, so, is there a way to delay *every* iteration?

Comment: Found this link somewhat helpful: http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/svgScaleinHTML.htm

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can add the `end` event of a SMIL animated element to the [`begin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin) attribute.
Also, you can add multiple values, separated by `;` to this `begin` attribute :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="100px">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="15" fill="blue">
    <animate id="op" attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity"
             from="1" to="0" dur="3s" begin="3s;op.end+3s" />
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Marvellous, thank you! I was confused at first, because I had not realised that this does not work with `repeatCount`.

Comment: well actually `repeatCount` is still active and the `end` event fires at the end of the finite `repeatCount`.

Comment: I suppose I should be more specific and say the animation never ends if you have `repeatCount="indefinite"` - the `end` event is never reached! I don't see a specific mention of a default on MDN, but I assume it is set to 1 if not defined.

Comment: Well actually it is ignored if the duration is set : [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#ComputingActiveDur) but yes if repeatCount is set to `indefinite`, `end` won't fire, ever. That's why I said "at the end of the **finite** `repeatCount`"

Comment: Hello Kaiido,
I don't see a repeat count in your example, why does the animation start itself again?
In my case the animation doesn't.

Comment: @BlueLovag as said in the answer, it uses the `end` event (`op.end`) The syntax is [id of the animate element].end ensure you've set the `id` correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Define dummy loop and set relative start time.  See 
[How to make SVG Loop Animation?](http://codepen.io/danjiro/blog/how-to-make-svg-loop-animation)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="200px">
  <rect>
    <animate id="o1" begin="0;o1.end" dur="10s"
    attributeName="visibility" from="hide" to="hide"/>
  </rect>
  <circle fill="orange" cx="-50" cy="100" r="20">
    <animate begin="o1.begin" 
    attributeName="cx" from="250" to="50" dur="5.05s"/>
  </circle>
  <circle fill="blue" cx="150" cy="100" r="50" />
  <circle fill="orange" cx="-50" cy="100" r="20">
    <animate begin="o1.begin+5s" 
    attributeName="cx" from="50" to="250" dur="5.05s"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Below an example of "closing eyes"... thanks to the suggestions in this thread.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 16"><g>
  <g >
  <ellipse cx="9.45" cy="7.7" rx="0.96" ry="0.96" style="stroke: none; fill: black;">
   <animate id="op" attributeName="ry" attributeType="XML"
             to="0.1"
             begin="3s;op.end+3s" dur="0.15s"
             fill="remove" repeatCount="2"
            />
  </ellipse>
  <ellipse cx="14.6" cy="7.8" rx="0.8" ry="0.8" style="stroke: none; fill: black;">
   <animate id="op" attributeName="ry" attributeType="XML"
             to="0.1"
             begin="3s;op.end+3s" dur="0.15s"
             fill="remove" repeatCount="2"
            />
  </ellipse>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your animation to alternate (similar to what [`animation-direction: alternate;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction) does in CSS), and you want to have a different delay for the initial/start/first repetition vs subsequent repetitions, here I provide two workarounds. See [this GitHub issue in SVG Working Group repo](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/881).

#### Solution 1: Using two animation elements

```xml
<circle fill="#f5ca20" r="5" cx="12" cy="12">
  <animate id="anim1" attributeName="r" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="3s; anim2.end + 5s" to="10" keyTimes="0; 1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.37, 0, 0.63, 1"/>
  <animate id="anim2" attributeName="r" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="anim1.end + 5s"     to="5"  keyTimes="0; 1" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.37, 0, 0.63, 1"/>
</circle>
```

#### Solution 2: Using combination of `values` and `keyTimes` attributes

```xml
<circle fill="#f5ca20" r="5" cx="12" cy="12">
  <animate attributeName="r" dur="12s" begin="3s" values="5; 10; 10; 5; 5" keyTimes="0; 0.083; 0.5; 0.583; 1" repeatDur="indefinite" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.37, 0, 0.63, 1; 0, 0, 1, 1; 0.37, 0, 0.63, 1; 0, 0, 1, 1"/>
</circle>
```

In this approach you should calculate the total duration of animations plus delays and assign it to `dur` and also calculate the `keyTimes` values for your durations. For my example, the total duration is `12s` and the times <sub><sup>3s</sup></sub>  1s  5s  1s  5s maps to `keyTimes="0; 0.083; 0.5; 0.583; 1"`.

#### Notes for my examples

- `calcMode="..."` and `keySplines="..."` are optional (they specify [timing interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/calcMode))
- The initial animation delay is **3 seconds**
- The animations (shrinking and expansion) each take **1 second**
- The delay before starting to shrink/expand is **5 Seconds**

---

Both of the above produce the following result:

[image: The animated image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the additive/accumulative attributes of the svg. This is an example that i got from [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/)

```css
svg {
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="100">
  <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />

  <animate xlink:href="#orange-circle" attributeName="cx" from="0" to="100" additive="sum" repeatCount="3" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines=".42 0 1 1" dur="1s" begin="click" fill="freeze" />
</svg>
```

In fact here is a better exaample (same source)

```css
svg {
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="150">
  <style>
    rect {
      -moz-transform-origin: 75px 75px;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }
  </style>
  <rect id="deepPink-rectangle" width="50" height="50" x="50" y="50" fill="deepPink" />
  
  <animateTransform 
           xlink:href="#deepPink-rectangle"
           attributeName="transform" 
           attributeType="XML"
           type="rotate"
           from="0 75 75"
           to="360 75 75" 
           dur="2s"
           begin="0s; 5s; 9s; 17s;"
           end="2s; 8s; 15s; 25s;"
           fill="freeze" 
           restart="whenNotActive"
           />
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think this specifically addresses the question. I needed a delay on an indefinite number of repetitions, where these examples appear to be finite.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more elaborated version of Danjiro Daiwa's example without the hidden rectangle to synchronise the animation and without resorting to setting the orange circles out of the visible area to hide them, using `opacity="0"` instead. There are four animation running at the same time, a1/a2 for the movement, o1/o2 to hide the orange doppelganger circles when they're moving behind/over the blue circle, r1-r4 to change the radius `r` and f1-f4 to change `fill` colour.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="200px">
  <circle fill="#f70" cx="0" cy="100" r="20" opacity="0">
    <animate id="a1" attributeName="cx" begin="0s;a2.end" from="250" to="50" dur="3s"/>
    <animate id="o1" attributeName="opacity" begin="a1.begin" end="a1.end" from="1" to="1"/>
    <animate id="r1" attributeName="r" begin="a1.begin" from="20" to="15" dur="1.5s"/>
    <animate id="r2" attributeName="r" begin="r1.end" from="15" to="20" dur="1.5s"/>
    <animate id="f1" attributeName="fill" begin="a1.begin" from="#f70" to="#c00" dur="1.5s"/>
    <animate id="f2" attributeName="fill" begin="f1.end" from="#c00" to="#f70" dur="1.5s"/>
  </circle>

  <circle fill="blue" cx="150" cy="100" r="50" />

  <circle fill="#f90" cx="0" cy="100" r="20" opacity="0">
    <animate id="a2" attributeName="cx" begin="a1.end" from="50" to="250" dur="2s"/>
    <animate id="o2" attributeName="opacity" begin="a2.begin" end="a2.end" from="1" to="1"/>
    <animate id="r3" attributeName="r" begin="a2.begin" from="20" to="25" dur="1s"/>
    <animate id="r4" attributeName="r" begin="r3.end" from="25" to="20" dur="1s"/>
    <animate id="f3" attributeName="fill" begin="a2.begin" from="#f70" to="#ff0" dur="1s"/>
    <animate id="f4" attributeName="fill" begin="f3.end" from="#ff0" to="#f70" dur="1s"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```